# Localization asp .net core email templates

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-localization

I have used localization globalization throughout my site (following the instructions in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.1). The site is an asp.net core 2.0 MVC web application.

The resources I use are resx-files and I inject them with IHtmlLocalizer localizer
and IViewLocalizer viewLocalizer in the views. Now I am making e-mail templates and try to use the same set up there but it fails. The engine I use to compile the razor files into pure HTML doesn't find the resources. I use the engine Razorlight. Error message:  "The type or namespace name 'SharedResource' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)". I definitely have the correct using statements. The set up is the same as in my another cshtml-documents in the site.